# Remove invalid XML after xmllint validation

Tags: bash, validation, scripting, xsd, xmllint

I receive a large XML file and often the XML file do not validate to schema file.
Instead of droping the whole xml file I would like to remove the "invalid" content and save the rest of the XML file.

I'm using xmllint to validate the xml by this command:

```
xmllint -schema testSchedule.xsd testXML.xml
```

The XSD file (in this example named testSchedule.xsd):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://www.testing.dk" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="MasterData">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="Items">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="Item" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0">
                <xs:complexType>
                  <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element type="xs:integer" name="Id" minOccurs="1"/>
                    <xs:element type="xs:integer" name="Width" minOccurs="1"/>
                    <xs:element type="xs:integer" name="Height" minOccurs="0"/>
                    <xs:element type="xs:string" name="Remark"/>
                  </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
              </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

And the XML file (In this example named testXML.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<MasterData xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://www.testing.dk">
    <Items>
        <Item>
            <Id>1</Id>
            <Width>10</Width>
            <Height>100</Height>
            <Remark>This is OK</Remark>
        </Item>
        <Item>
            <Id>2</Id>
            <Width>20</Width>
            <Height>200</Height>
            <Remark>This is OK - But is missing Height a non mandatory field</Remark>
        </Item>
        <Item>
            <Id>3</Id>
            <Height>300</Height>
            <Remark>This is NOT OK - Missing the mandatory Width</Remark>
        </Item>
        <Item>
            <Id>4</Id>
            <Width>TheIsAString</Width>
            <Height>200</Height>
            <Remark>This is NOT OK - Width is not an integer but a string</Remark>
        </Item>
        <Item>
            <Id>5</Id>
            <Width>50</Width>
            <Height>500</Height>
            <Remark>This is OK and the last</Remark>
        </Item>
    </Items>
</MasterData>
```

Then I get the this result of the xmllint command:

```
testXML.xml:18: element Height: Schemas validity error : Element '{http://www.testing.dk}Height': This element is not expected. Expected is ( {http://www.testing.dk}Width ).
testXML.xml:23: element Width: Schemas validity error : Element '{http://www.testing.dk}Width': 'TheIsAString' is not a valid value of the atomic type 'xs:integer'.
testXML.xml fails to validate
```

And that is all correct - There is two errors in the XML file.

Now I would like to have a tool of some kind to remove entry 3 and 4 so I end up with this result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<MasterData xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://www.testing.dk">
    <Items>
        <Item>
            <Id>1</Id>
            <Width>10</Width>
            <Height>100</Height>
            <Remark>This is OK</Remark>
        </Item>
        <Item>
            <Id>2</Id>
            <Width>20</Width>
            <Height>200</Height>
            <Remark>This is OK - But is missing Height a non mandatory field</Remark>
        </Item>
        <Item>
            <Id>5</Id>
            <Width>50</Width>
            <Height>500</Height>
            <Remark>This is OK and the last</Remark>
        </Item>
    </Items>
</MasterData>
```

Does anybody in here have a tool that can do this?
I'm currently using bash scripting and the xmllint.
I really hope somebody can help.

Comment: You can use XSLT. XSLT allows you to transform well-formed XML documents (even if invalid). Add an XSLT tag to your questions and you should get some suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that with this XSLT stylesheet, which you can run in any environment which supports XSLT 1.0 (most languages), using an command line tool such as `xsltproc` (`libxslt`) or Saxon, a browser or an online tool. Here is an example.

If you feed your original XML file as input to a XSLT transformer with the following stylesheet it will produce the result you have shown in your second XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0"
    xmlns:t="http://www.testing.dk">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="t:Item[t:Id     and not(number(t:Id))]"/>
    <xsl:template match="t:Item[t:Width  and not(number(t:Width))]"/>
    <xsl:template match="t:Item[t:Height and not(number(t:Height))]"/>
    <xsl:template match="t:Item[not(t:Width)]"/>
    <xsl:template match="t:Item[not(t:Id)]"/>
    <xsl:template match="t:Item[not(t:Remark)]"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The first `<xsl:template>` block simply copies all nodes from the source tree to the result tree. It has lower precedence than the specific templates which match nodes by their name.

Since matches are done in XPath which requires namespace-qualified selectors, your default namespace was declared in the `<xsl:stylesheet>` opening tag and mapped to a prefix that was used to qualify the tag names.

Each template uses an XPath expression to test if a specific child element is present or not in `Item`, or if that child is present, if it is a number (according to the XSD).

I'm using XSLT 1.0, which is more widely supported and should be easier to find in your environment. But if you can use a XSLT 2.0 processor, you could use XSLT 2.0 features such as support for XSD types, and instead of comparing your values to number type, you could compare them to specific types like `xsd:integer`.

You can verify the transformation performed on your example XML by that stylesheet in this **[XSLT Fiddle](http://xsltransform.net/94hvTyJ)**.

If you create a XML document containing the code above and place it in a file named `stylesheet.xsl` you can run the transformation using `xsltproc` (which probably exists in your environment) using:

```
xsltproc stylesheet.xsl testXML.xml > fixedXML.xml
```

Comment: Thanks for good and fast help.
The files stated is test files with a fair small amount of data and errors. The XML file I receive is HUGE!! and the schema is over 3.000 lines long. As I see it the XSLT solution can handle wellknown errors but the I get a lot of different validation error each time - This happens due to corrupt data - so I have a BIG difficulties making a XSLT the can handle this.

Comment: Actually I posted a simple XSLT 1.0 compatible example because you could easily find it available in your environment. But you might still consider XSLT 2.0 though, since your task is to *transform* XML documents. XSLT 2.0 has schema-aware features and can handle automatically much more than I have shown here. See http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-schemaxslt/ . Add a XSLT tag or ask a new question asking for XSLT 2.0 solutions mentioning these requirements as well. You should get some interesting solutions that you could possibly use.